# Performing an HTML substitution from AjaxResponse rather than using a wrapper

Tags: ajax

I have an autocomplete textfield whose autocomplete_route_parameters is updated on the `onChange` event of a textfield, which is filled by a jQuery UI datepicker. Everything works, but after the update of the list the datepicker, which was closed after the selection of the date, shows up again. So I thought, well, I'll just use jquery to close it again.

This means that the ajax callback cannot simply return a renderable array, but rather an `AjaxResponse`; the problem is that I don't understand how to use a form element inside a `ReplaceCommand`. If before the change I had

```
function seduta_senato_form_datetime_changed(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['struttura-input'] ;
}
```

now I should say something along the lines of

```
function seduta_senato_form_datetime_changed(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse() ;
  $response
  ->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#ajax-wrapper', "<div id='ajax-wrapper'>" . $form['struttura-input']->??? . '</div>'))
  return $response ;
}
```

but the form element has to be rendered somehow, otherwise it will simply appear in the HTML as Array.

I thought this would be simple, since for sure the functionality that renders the changed element is already there, but the research I made gave me only rather intricate solutions. Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first example needs an ajax wrapper div too, so $form['struttura-input'] should include this already. If you really need to add a wrapper, then don't try to concatenate a string and an array. Add the wrapper div to the form array, either with a `'#type' => 'container'` element or simply a #prefix and #suffix.

Comment: Yes, I know that I don't need a wrapper div if I use `AjaxResponse`, I just changed as little as I could from the solution returning a renderable array.

Answer (score 0):

So, I *used the source*, and I found out that `Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand` calls `getRenderedContent()`, I found an implementation in `CommandWithAttachedAssetsTrait` where I saw that it expects an array, as I should have well known. So I ended up with the following calls:

```
$response
  ->addCommand(new RemoveCommand('label[for^="edit-struttura-input"]'))
  ->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('input[id^="edit-struttura-input"]', array( $form['struttura-input'] )))
  ->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-field-next-field-to-edit', 'focus')  )
```

Note that I removed the wrapper, as suggested by @4k4, but then I had to select on a match on the start of the ID of the element, and to remove the label, since it is added by each new rendering. As a command to get rid of the datepicker I simply moved the focus to the next element to edit, which is very convenient to the user.